# Syntax problems using a viewModel with my view

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I created this class:

```
public class PageMeta
{
    public string User { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public string Keywords { get; set; }
    public string Url { get; set; }
    public string UrlShort { get; set; }
    public string InfoBox { get; set; }
}
```

And then this model:

```
 public class HomeIndexViewModel
    {
        public HomeIndexViewModel()
        {
            PageMeta = new PageMeta();
        }
        public PageMeta PageMeta { get; set; }
    }
```

And tried to use it like this:

```
var homeIndex = new HomeIndexViewModel { // 1
  PageMeta.Title = "ABC" // 2
};
```

But it gives me an error in VS2010 saying:

- "Cannot initialize type
  HomeIndexViewModel with a collection
  initializer because it does not
  implement IEnumberable" "
- Cannot resolve symbol "Add" <-
  Message is in red and under where I
  mark //2

I hope someone can give me some advice. I did try commenting out the constructor public HomeIndexViewModel() but that didn't help me as I still get the same message.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's the correct syntax to use an [object initializer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384062.aspx) in C#:

```
var homeIndex = new HomeIndexViewModel 
{
    PageMeta = new PageMeta 
    {
        Title = "ABC",
        User = "DEF"
    }
};
```

Comment: Thanks Darin. I thought what the other poster was saying didn't make sense and you confirmed this.